# php.ini blocks PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I recently tried to install kayako fusion helpdesk (ioncube) and found out a strange behaviour. When the installation is underway i am asked to turn off GPC magic quotes, so i created a php.ini file but to my horror after creation of a custom php.ini the setup pages goes blank on further checking i found that no matter what is written inside the php.ini or even if it is empty adding a php.ini file will make the setup page go blank. Asked kayako for help all they would say is PDO is not enabled and for me to enable it. 
Checking I found that with no php.ini file the PDO is enabled but the moment i add a php.ini file the PDO is disabled.

Any idea why the php.ini file is blocking PDO?

Comment: Have you checked your hosting company's FAQ?

Comment: yes the PDO module is installed the problem was that while creating a custom `php.ini` file i needed to add the IonCube references because without that any scripts on the site that require IonCube to work will no longer function PDO functionality included

Comment: Same problem here. In my php.ini file, I needed to make sure I was pointing to the correct loadable extensions folder. Without this, PDO does not want to load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After spending a few hours where my hosting service support desk kept going offline every time i asked them for help, I finally discovered the trouble.

IonCube is installed by default on the servers, however if you require adding custom settings such as increased memory sizes, file upload sizes or change other variables from the default on the server, you will need to create a custom `php.ini` file for processing. If you use a custom `php.ini` file on your site, if you do not add in the IonCube references any scripts on your site that require IonCube to work will no longer function. 
This is true of PDO functionality also.

In order to get it back, you will need to add the following lines to the bottom of your `php.ini` file:

```
[Zend]
zend_extension="/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so"
zend_extension_ts="/usr/local/IonCube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3_ts.so"
extension=pdo.so
extension=pdo_sqlite.so
extension=sqlite.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

The above is for PHP 5.3 ONLY. 
If you are running PHP 5.2, the above numbers must be changed to 5.2 and you can also add in other references for Zend Optimizer.
Please see this article on [adding IonCube and Zend for a PHP 5.2 site](https://billing.handsonwebhosting.com/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=224)